# Union doesn't give a correct result in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I have 2 criteria and I'm doing a union between them.

The first criteria contains Category, Marks, SUM(0)
The second criteria contains Category, SUM(0), Marks

The difference between these 2 criteria is that the first criteria displays data for the year 2017 and the second criteria displays for the year 2016. But in the resultant column the second criteria marks is always displayed as 0. Is there am going wrong with the union concept?

Comment: Also, the intention of following the above method is to find the TOP 5 Categories increased from 2016 to 2017 based on marks.

Comment: Also here you can use the mathematical growth function (new - old)/old, and so do (marks - marks ago)/marks ago, and then only select your top 5 from this measure using the topN function, where you can read the specs at http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/obis/topn

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would use a union report for this. You can use an 'ago' function where you can recreate the measure for a certain timeframe 'ago'. You can read the way to go at http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/obis/ago

Then you can add Marks (measure1), Marks 'ago' (measure2) and category (your dimension).

Can this help solve your problem or is there another reason why you went for a union report here?

Comment: Hi Beerden, The years will be chosen from the prompts by the user. So, will this method work?

Comment: Yes this will work. You dynamically choose a year and the ago function will calculate the value from the previous year. When you select the year 2017 you will get the results from 2017 (in the normal measure) and the results from 2016 (when you have created the 'ago' measure). You can do this in the RPD in the expression builder, derived from a logical column. To calculate the value of the previous year you put ago(measure, time dimension year, 1) to have 1 year ago. You must have a time dimension though. The ago function doesn't work with normal logical dimensions.